# Exporting data to csv from database fails for column with datatype 'timestamp without timezone'

Tags: postgresql

Trying to export data to csv.
Query used to export-

```
copy (SELECT * FROM public.carrier_booking) 
to 'C:\Users\Public\A.csv' 
with csv HEADER
```

The `carrier_booking` table has following rows

```
id bigint,
public_id character varying(50),
"number" character varying(50),
status character varying(50),
created_by character varying(50) ,
created_at_utc timestamp without time zone ,
updated_by character varying(50) ,
updated_at_utc timestamp without time zone,
transport_mode character varying(100),
CONSTRAINT pk_carrier_booking PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

The data in csv file is as follows-

`id,public_id,number,status,payload,created_by,created_at_utc,updated_by,updated_at_utc,transport_mode 24,CBK593190,CB593190,CARRIER_ACCEPTED,"{""CreatedBy"": """", ""Containers"": [{""IsoCombinedCode"": """"}]}",SYSEM,2022-12-21 06:07:51.57578,SYSEM,2022-12-21 06:07:51.57578,""`

The `created_at_utc`  and `updated_at_utc`  columns have data `2022-12-21 06:07:51.57578`. However the exported CSV file just contains `06:07:52`

This creates problem when I try to import this csv file.

How can do I handle `'timestamp without time zone'` datatype while exporting to csv so that the data doesn't change?

Tried importing the csv file excluding the `created_at_utc`
and `updated_at_utc` columns-

```
COPY public.carrier_booking(created_at_utc
,updated_at_utc)
FROM 'C:\Users\Public\A.csv'
DELIMITER ','
csv HEADER
```

But this doesn't work since this columns are marked not null.

Comment: 1) *However the exported CSV file just contains 06:07:52*. No it doesn't. Your example CSV data clearly shows the complete values are there. So where are you getting the `06:07:52` value from? Is there another step in this process you have not included? 2) `public.carrier_booking(created_at_utc ,updated_at_utc)` means you want only include those columns not exclude them. Read the docs [Copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

Comment: Yes you are right, I was trying to see the csv file in excel, that is the reason it was showing rounded values with missing data, which when loaded to db, threw error